# Do dust bunnies form normally in microgravity?

Tags: life, cleaning

On Earth, dust, hair, and other assorted debris clump up into fuzzy lumps known as [dust bunnies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_bunny), which shelter parasites, set off allergies, clog air filters, and impede electronic-device cooling.

In microgravity, where dust *et al.* have no tendency to settle towards the ground, do dust bunnies still form as they do in macrogravity?  Are there measures taken to mitigate their formation?

(A google for "dust bunnies microgravity" brought up only [this article](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/11/181105105434.htm) about the behaviour of strongly-charged microscopic dust particles, plus a bunch of irrelevant hits about planetary accretion.)

Comment: @uhoh: Thanx!  Added.

Comment: I can understand "dust" showing up in articles on planetary accretion... but "bunnies"?!

Comment: @DrSheldon: The accretion of circumstellar dust into planetesimals was being compared to the accretion of terrestrial dust into dust bunnies, from what I saw when skimming the search-results page.

Comment: Just as an aside: the [2002 Interdisciplinary Research Ig Nobel Prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ig_Nobel_Prize_winners#2002) was awarded to Karl Kruszelnicki, "for performing a comprehensive survey of human belly button fluff – who gets it, when, what color, and how much.". Loose belly button fluff just might be the core agglomerator required for micro gravity dust bunnies. ;-)